# Session being reset inadvertently

Tags: asp.net, .net, session, session-state

I have a legacy ASP.NET application. It was converted from NET 2 to net 4.
It uses state server session.

At some point, the app opens a new page (in a new browser tab: link target = "_blank")

But after returning to calling page (tab), I discovered the session is reset, so current user is no longer used and app redirects to login page. Actually, SessionID remains unchanged, but IsSessionNew is set to true, and session has no variables set in it.

The app doesn't use Session.Abort or Session.Clear.

Even if I change session to InProc, and change the target for the links to _top, or _self, or remove entirely, the same thing happens - session got reset.

This is session setting in web.config (alternatively I used StateServer, but with same result)

```
<sessionState timeout="432000" cookieless="UseCookies" mode="InProc"/>
```

Any idea what can cause this?

Thank you.

Comment: The session cookie is maybe using a wrong path. Inspect the traffic (especially the cookies being send and received) using the browser debugger.

Comment: Place also the `domain` on the parameters, with out the www. of your domain.

Comment: @Lucero - can you give me more details how to do this? Thanks

Comment: @Aristos - can you give me more details how to do this? Thanks

Comment: No, I cannot - that depends on the browser which you're using.

Comment: See this answer and tell me if you do not understand it : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14033497/cookies-are-not-retaining-any-data-while-sent-as-part-of-a-webrequest/14033594#14033594

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally fixed the problem.
However, I didn't found the actual cause, but I found the module which caused the issue.
It was a aspx page which did 1001 things (it's basic functionality plus another approximatively 80 other things based on ajax calls (!!!). I didn't made that page !!!
But the part that caused the problem was a functionality that served an image file. 
So I rewrite that part as an ASHX handler, and then the code worked ok - the session remained open.